# How can I digitalize graph using Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, graph

I want to convert an image of a graph (plot) to corresponding data. Is there any python library to do this or maybe some sample code to learn from? 
If not, then how do i approach this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up writing what I needed from scratch.
Here's a link to the [python code](https://sites.google.com/site/gbbaux/plotdigitiser.py), and a [blog post including a screen shot](http://eumenidae.blogspot.com/2012/12/quick-n-dirty-wxpython-plot-digitiser.html).

Comment: I always use Engauge Digitizer: http://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/

Comment: You can use [this python script](https://pypi.org/project/PlotDigitizer/) Or better try [PlotDigitizer.com](https://plotdigitizer.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a digitizing software application, to convert graph images to data, that is to numbers.  im2graph is free and available for both Linux and Windows.  See http://www.im2graph.co.il.